# A sign condition on structure constants for the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

I want to prove a property of structure constants given a specific basis for the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{C})$ which I will now describe.

Let $e,f,h$ be the standard generators of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$; so
$$
e = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right), \quad f = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix}\right), \quad h = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{matrix}\right).
$$
Define a Lie algebra homomorphism $\sigma_n: \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C}) \to \mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{C})$ by
$$
\sigma_n(e) = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ & & & \ddots \\ 0 & 0 &&\dots & 0 & n-1 \\ 0 & 0 & & \dots & 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)
$$
and 
$$
\sigma_n(f) = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 &   \dots & & 0 \\ n-1 & 0 & 0 &   \dots & & 0 \\ 0 & n-2 & 0 &  \dots & & 0 \\  &  & &\ddots &  &  \\ 0 & 0 & & \dots & 1 & 0 \end{matrix}\right).
$$
That is, letting $\tilde{e} = \sigma_n(e)$ and $\tilde{f}=\sigma_n(f)$, we have
$$
(\tilde{e})_{i,j} = \left\{ \begin{matrix} i & \text{if } & i = j-1  \\ 0 & \text{else} \end{matrix} \right.
$$
and
$$
(\tilde{f})_{i,j} = \left\{ \begin{matrix} n-j & \text{if } & i = j+1  \\ 0 & \text{else} \end{matrix} \right..
$$
Thus, composing with the adjoint representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{C})$ we have realized $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{C})$ as a representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$.

Now, define $f_k$ to be the unique matrix in the kernel of the linear map $\mathrm{ad}_{\tilde{f}} = [\tilde{f}, \cdot]:\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{C}) \to \mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{C})$ whose only nonzero entries are positive integers which lie in the $k^{th}$ sub-diagonal, the least of which is 1.  So for example, $f_1 = \tilde{f}$ and in general 
$$
(f_k)_{i,j} =\left\{ \begin{matrix} \frac{1}{(n-i)!}(k+1)\dots (n-i+k) & \text{if } & i = j+k < n \\ 1 & \text{if } & i = j+k = n \\0 & \text{else} \end{matrix} \right..
$$
Note that $f_k$ is a lowest weight vector for the action of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ on $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{C})$.

Using this, define a basis for $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{C})$ as follows.  Let $a^+ = \mathrm{ad}_{\tilde{e}} = [\tilde{e},\cdot]$ and define $v_{k,j} = (a^+)^{k+j}(f_k)$.  Note that $f_k = v_{k,-k}$.  One observes that, with $k$ fixed, the set $\{v_{k,j}\}$ forms a basis for a $(2k+1)$-dimensional sub-representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{C})$ which is irreducible.

I want to understand the map $\mathrm{ad}_{f_{n-1}} = [f_{n-1}, \cdot]$ where
$$
f_{n-1} = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ & & \vdots & \\ 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \end{matrix}\right).
$$
The first thing to observe is that $[f_{n-1},v_{k,j}]$ is a linear combination of the $v_{k,j-(n-1)}$; that is, bracketing a basis vector supported in the $j^{th}$ off diagonal with $f_{n-1}$ takes us to the $j-(n-1)$ off diagonal. So most of the structure constants are 0 and we need only look at input that are upper triangular.  Moreover, as all the $v_{k,j}$ have only integer entries, the structure constants will be rational numbers.

**Here is the main problem:**
Write 
$$
[f_{n-1}, v_{n-1-k,n-1-j}] = \sum_{i=j}^{n-1} c_{i,j,k}v_{i,-j}.
$$
I want to show that $c_{i,i,i-1}$ and $c_{i,i-1,i-1}$ are non-zero and have the same sign.

For example, it is not hard to show that $c_{n-1,n-1,n-2} = 2(n-1)$ and $c_{n-1,n-2,n-2}=2$.

One can come close to proving this using the Jacobi identity:

We have 
$$
[f_{n-1},v_{n-i,n-i}] = c_{i-1,i-1,i-1}v_{i-1,-(i-1)} + c_{i,i-1,i-1}v_{i,-(i-1)} + \dots
$$
and
\begin{align*}
[f_{n-1},v_{n-i,n-i}] & = [f_{n-1},[\tilde{e},v_{n-i,n-i-1}] \\
& = -[\tilde{e},[v_{n-i,n-i-1},f_{n-1}]] - [v_{n-i,n-i-1},[f_{n-1},\tilde{e}]] \\
& = (c_{i,i,i-1}v_{i,-(i-1)} + \dots) + [v_{n-i,n-i-1},v_{n-1,-(n-2)}].
\end{align*}
So it follows that $c_{i,i-1,i-1} = c_{i,i,i-1} + (\text{constant})$.

I have been searching for some inductive assumption I could make on $[v_{n-i,n-i-1},v_{n-1,-(n-2)}]$ but so far haven't come up with anything useful.

Another approach I have tried is to model the $n$-dimensional irreducible representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ by homogeneous polynomials of degree $n-1$ in two variables.  Then $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ acts via differential operators: $e \mapsto x d/dy$, $f \mapsto y d/dx$ and $f_k \mapsto y^k(d/dx)^k$.  Using this model makes it easier to give a general formula for the $v_{k,j}$.  But I have so far not succeeded in computing these structure constants directly.

My main question is whether the sign result I'm looking for is known, possibly as a special case of a more general result.  Has anyone seen a similar computation who can point me to a reference?

Thank you and apologies if anything is confusing or inaccurate.  I am not an expert on representation theory or Lie algebras.  The motivation for this question comes from another computation important to my work, analyzing the Jimbo-Miwa-Ueno isomonodromy equations for systems of ordinary differential equations with irregular singularities.  Any insights or comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Charles, welcome to MO. As it is, your question is very long, and I suspect your real question "hides" in the long text you've written. I'd advise you to break your question into a concise question, background etc. Otherwise it is very hard to help you

Comment: I agree with @AmirSagiv that it's difficult to get a quick idea of the question, but, at an immediate glance, I suspect you want the [Serre relations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Chevalley-SerreRelations.html).  It may also help to see [Carter - Simple groups of Lie type](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1013112).